# A href tag with display block and text-align fills the width

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML:

```
<a style="display:block;text-align:right" href="link.com">Test Link</a>
```

I want to place a link to the far right of a parent DIV. However, I tried the above code but it leads the link to fill all the space meaning it's clickable across the whole width of the div.

The only ways to avoid this are to give a fixed width to the link or to wrap the link in another DIV. Is there any other way? Or to float the link but it will break the layout

Answer (score 2):

You can use a float for 'floating' it to the right side of your div.

```
<a style="float:right" href="link.com">Test Link</a>
```

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wstmrtgz/

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that float is not an option as it will break the layout

Comment: Could you provide additional information.. Or a fiddle more accurately describing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/a99gustL/)

I've used `display:inline-block` and `float`:

```
.parent {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

.link {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
```

**EDIT:** Having seen your comment about not being able to use floats, you can also do this using `display:inline-block` and fixed widths.

Answer (score 0):

float will fix this

dont forget the clear the float !

```
<div style="width: 200px; background-color: red;">
    <a style="float:right;" href="link.com">Test Link</a>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div
```

see the difference with and without the clear in the following fiddles!

With clear

http://jsfiddle.net/j9q8jgvm/

without clear

http://jsfiddle.net/j9q8jgvm/